After Electron package .env file variable are not setting up
In my Electron Project  I have my env files like this

and I have my package.json file like this

Issue is in the development when i use npm start .env variable setting up , but when I use npm package:win to package the project the .env variable are not setting up , How to fix this ?
After Package these are not setting up ,


dotenv not working correctly during packaging in an Electron app. Can go for these three options

Use Electron Forge with Webpack
Use a Configuration Service
Use a JSON File and Create an Environment Handler

